# Using the Dart/Flutter Postgres Package to store dates and null dates needs two separate commands

Tags: postgresql, sqlpackage

I am using the Postgres Package ([On the pub.dev site](https://pub.dev/packages/postgres)) to UPDATE records in a very simple database. It has two fields: a Text field prime key named number, and a Date field named date_of_birth.

If the date_of_birth is a valid DateTime string then all is well (as can be seen from the code below). But if date_of_birth is unknown (so I set to null) the UPDATE fails:

```
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';
void main() async {
  final conn = PostgreSQLConnection(
   'localhost',
    XXXXX,
    'XXXXX',
    username: 'XXXXX',
    password: 'XXXXX',
  );

  await conn.open();

  DateTime dob = DateTime.now();

  var results;
  results = await conn.query('''
    UPDATE account_details
    SET date_of_birth = '$dob'
    WHERE number = '123123'
  ''');

  await conn.close();
}
```

If I set:

```
dob = null;
```

The program fails with the error:

```
Unhandled exception:
PostgreSQLSeverity.error 22007: invalid input syntax for type date: "null"
```

So I need to include a check on the dob field and the program now looks like this:

```
  DateTime dob = DateTime.now();
  dob = null;

  var results;
  if (dob == null) {
    results = await conn.query('''
    UPDATE account_details
    SET date_of_birth = null
    WHERE number = '123123'
  ''');
  } else {
    results = await conn.query('''
    UPDATE account_details
    SET date_of_birth = '$dob'
    WHERE number = '123123'
  ''');
  }
```

That works fine for my simple database, but in my real App. I have a number of date fields in one table. So I have to do a check for each possible combination of those date values - writing a code block for each!

Can anyone tell me how I can UPDATE both null and a valid date using a single statement please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quoting the query parameters yourself. NEVER do this. In addition to the sort of problem you have just seen it also leaves you open to a trivial SQL injection attack.

The library you are using will have some way of putting placeholders into the query text and passing variables when executing the query. Use that.

Comment: Thanks very much @RichardHuxton.  I thought the lack of 'substitution values' was not right.  On closer inspection of the package's limited documentation I was able to find them.

You are quite right in what you say too: by using the substitution values it happily accepts null or a valid datetime string with just one line of code.  Thanks again.